# Laravel Installation " Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages."

Tags: php, ubuntu, laravel, composer-php, server

I'm trying to create a laravel project. I'm new to laravel and composer. My composer.json file reads

```
{
    "name": "jrodriguez/sapme",
    "description": "Sap Replacement Server.",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "myname",
            "email": "myemai"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "laravel/framework": "~5.0"
    }
}
```

When I run composer diagnose it says everything is ok.

when I run composer create-project laravel/laravel --prefer-dist I get an error that my requirements can't be resolved.

Comment: what version of php do you have installed? See also [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0#server-requirements) for other system dependencies (mcrypt, tokenizer, mbstring and openssl)

Comment: Can you give us the entire error (should be a dozen lines or more)? It usually gives a lot of information on *why* it can't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

> composer dump-autoload
>
> composer install

If that doesn't help, which version of PHP are you using?

The requirement for Laravel 5.0 are:

```
PHP >= 5.4, PHP < 7
Mcrypt PHP Extension
OpenSSL PHP Extension
Mbstring PHP Extension
Tokenizer PHP Extension
```